# $d$-Cauchy $\Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon>0 \exists N\in\mathbb N (\text{diam}(\{x_n:n\ge N\}) \le \epsilon)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cauchy-sequences

I want to prove that a sequence is $d$-Cauchy iff $$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb N :\text{diam}(\{x_n:n\ge N\}) \le \epsilon.$$

**Definition** of $d$-Cauchy sequence in a metric space $(M,d)$:
A sequence $x_n$ is $d$-Cauchy in $(M,d)$ if $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N\in\mathbb N \forall m,n\ge N\ (d(x_m,x_n) < \epsilon)$$

Note the **strict inequality** in the definition, because of which I've asked this question.

$[\Rightarrow]$ is pretty obvious. If $x_n$ is $d$-Cauchy, $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N\in\mathbb N \forall m,n\ge N\ (d(x_m,x_n) < \epsilon)\implies \sup\{a,b: a,b\in \{x_n:n\ge N\}\} \le \epsilon$$

$[\Leftarrow]$ direction is what is troubling me because of the strict inequality.

How do I proceed?

Comment: The assertion that you want to prove makes no sense. What is $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Notice that the strict inequality is not relevant. I guess the question is $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence $\iff$ for all $\varepsilon >0$, there is $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $\text{diam}\{x_n\mid n\geq N\}\leq \varepsilon,$ (which is straightforwrd from the definition).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Edited.

Comment: @Surb I agree that the strict inequality is not relevant, but how do I produce the definition with strict inequality while proving $[\Leftarrow]$ direction?

Comment: 1. Fix $\epsilon$.  2. Use $\epsilon' = 0.8964 \epsilon$ when invoking your given condition containing the $\le$ sign.

Comment: Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $\eta\in (0,\varepsilon )$. Then, there is $N$ s.t. $$\text{diam}\{x_n\mid n\geq N\}\leq \eta<\varepsilon .$$ I let you conclude. @strawberry-sunshine